# How to change admin router?

Tags: magento, url-routing

How to change admin routing? For example:

My current url is "http://www.something.com/index.php/admin/Pos".

Now want to rewrite into "http://www.something.com/index.php/Pos".

Is it possible in Magento?

Comment: @zzzz: be careful, I don't understand why you would rename "magento" into "magneto" in this post...

Comment: @adrien54 Ohh.. this was a silly mistake, as i saw the wrong spell mark and just did right click and selected the 1st option .. i was expecting the correct spelling of Magento ... will take care next time ... thnx.

Comment: If it seems alright, please remove negative vote.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure `admin/Pos` is your admin url path?  Usually it should be `admin` only.

Go to app/etc/local.xml file and you will see something like

```
<admin>
  <routers>
    <adminhtml>
      <args>
        <frontName><![CDATA[admin]]></frontName>
      </args>
    </adminhtml>
  </routers>
</admin>
```

Change `admin` to `Pos` or whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks amit, it works but i have also another admin part called "Pos" where user can login and do order. so i want to run both admin and Pos (point to My extension index controller).

Comment: What is the current url of another admin part? Which module are you using? you need to find config.xml file in that module and you will see "Pos" in routers section which you need to update.

Comment: URL of another admin part is "http://www.something.com/index.php/admin/Pos". I am using "pos" module.

Comment: AFAIK, you must use admin or frontend router before using any module router. So  `admin/Pos` can't be changed to `Pos` only in Url. You can change it to `Pos/someothername`  because first it will load admin section using first `Pos` and using `someothername` it will load your module.

Comment: Thanks amitshree for reply, will apply solution as you posted.